# Python class decorator converting element access to attribute access

Tags: python, decorator

I'm looking for a decorator for Python class that would convert any element access to attribute access, something like this:

```
@DictAccess
class foo(bar):
    x = 1
    y = 2

myfoo = foo()
print myfoo.x # gives 1
print myfoo['y'] # gives 2
myfoo['z'] = 3
print myfoo.z # gives 3
```

Does such decorator exist somewhere already? If not, what is the proper way to implement it?  Should I wrap `__new__` on class `foo` and add `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` properties to the instance? How make these properly bound to the new class then? I understand that `DictMixin` can help me support all `dict` capabilities, but I still have to get the basic methods in the classes somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator needs to add a *__getitem__* method and a *__setitem__* method:

```
def DictAccess(kls):
    kls.__getitem__ = lambda self, attr: getattr(self, attr)
    kls.__setitem__ = lambda self, attr, value: setattr(self, attr, value)
    return kls
```

That will work fine with your example code:

```
class bar:
    pass

@DictAccess
class foo(bar):
    x = 1
    y = 2

myfoo = foo()
print myfoo.x # gives 1
print myfoo['y'] # gives 2
myfoo['z'] = 3
print myfoo.z # gives 3
```

That test code produces the expected values:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: And `__delitem__()`. Also, you may want to prevent stomping on, say, `__dict__`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I agree, there are a number of ways to extend the basic recipe (perhaps including the full dict API provided by *MutableMapping* and perhaps trying to protect parts of the object's namespace).  For now, the code above is simple enough to get the OP started on this adventure :-)

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Stomping on `__dict__` is not an issue - I know what attributes will be accessed. But a possibility of getting functionality like DictMixin does would be interesting. Any ideas how to do that?