# Python: Directly access to attribute in a dict-like way

Tags: python, oop, numpy, attributes

I have a class that handles a Numpy matrix and some additional infos.

```
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.values = v

plop = MyClass(np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

The matrix being named **values**, to access it, I write:

```
plop.values[1, 1]  # Returns 4
```

Is it possible to access it directly? I mean, doing:

```
plop[1, 1]  # Should returns 4 too
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106076/python-class-decorator-converting-element-access-to-attribute-access) but it seams that this solution allows only one level of `[]`.

Thanks!

Comment: `plop = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]]); plop[1, 1]` ?

Comment: Actually, there are others attributes to MyClass that I didn't write here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this method to you class

```
def __getitem__(self, indices):
    return self.values[indices]
```

Also, given the opportunity, it would be useful to see how `__getitem__` and *slice objects* work

Answer (score -1):

you access it directly I think.

plop = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

plot[1, 1]

Comment: To quote OP: "there are others attributes to MyClass that I didn't write here" so `plop` must be an instance of `MyClass`